# Linux doesn't seems to capture some characters

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos

Last night I was making some bash script, just using proc and cat.
But suddenly, I think it broke or something like that my on Linux Installation.

What I can't do at the moment of posting is:
PuTTY doesn't seems to "accept"/register/capture the following keys. (Tried on 2 computers)

- a
- i
- p
- s
- f
- m
- w
- c
- v
- b

I've tried on 3 servers.

- Debian 7 32Bit - nothing wrong
- CentOS 6 32Bit - doesn't work
- Ubuntu 12.04 32Bit -doesn't work

I haven't tried to reinstall them because my CentOS server runs cPanel and I don't want to start over again and my Ubuntu server runs like 8 TeamSpeak3 server (not a big job but people will complain).

Screenshot:
[image]

[image]

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Hang on, saving CPU Info" &&
CPU=$(sudo cat /proc/cpuinfo) &&

cat >test.txt <<EOF
$CPU

EOF
```

I'm new to bash scripting :s

Comment: you assume us having too much knowledge of your setup. you start talking about a bash script, just "using" proc and cat, and suddenly you talk about putty. where does this now come from? have you neglected to tell us something which involves use of putty, maybe? and what suddenly "cPanel" has to do which your bash script is a riddle too.

Comment: My bash script was just to get CPUInfo (grep /proc/cpuinfo) and store it on a file (cat > test.txt <<EOF $CPU EOF). Setup of CentOS is ordinary cPanel and the two others just VNC.  And if you didn't knew it already, PuTTY is used for SSH and to connect to your server >.> . And the cPanel thingy is just because I don't want to setup it again (took me ~2hours)

Comment: From more than one computer you had this same problem to two different servers? From a single computer you had this problem on one remote computer but not on another remote computer?

Comment: now where did your bash script actually run? and what computer did you use to look at the result?  which computer is the one which has problems now? Or does it mean, that on every machine you've been running it, the machine somehow breaks?

Comment: @EtanReisner This 'error' occurs on two server out of three where I've run this bash script on. I've connected with two different computers via PuTTY and via a Java Applet(from SolusVM) and this 'error' still occurs.

Comment: @Bushmills I've ran the bash on the three servers, only two of them 'broke'. It's maybe something about the Linux Distro...

Comment: There is no possible way that a script as simple as the one you claim to have run could have done anything of this sort. (That being said there is no reason to use a heredoc for that script either but <shrug>.) Something else must be going on. Are you using saved putty sessions for the servers or the default session for them? How does the output from `env` and `locale` compare on each remote computer?

Comment: What breaks,  the  servers  or  the  client  running  putty?

Comment: @Bushmills The servers it seems.

Comment: @Etan Reisner I'll take a look on it and I'll update the post with it. EDIT: can't do it, those characters are in it...

Comment: So  you  grep something  from /proc/cpuinfo,  and  as  consequence  the server breaks?  I find  that  pretty hard to believe.

Comment: What happens if you type `ctrl-v` and then one of the broken characters? (ctrl-v will not output anything by itself) Use scp or something to send that file to the remote machine and then run it.

Comment: @EtanReisner It also happens just by typing. The username & password input works but once logged in it doesn't work good. :s

Comment: I didn't ask about normal typing. Though that login difference is interesting. I was specifically asking about `ctrl-v` then `a` (for example) because ctrl-v is quote-next-character. It may very well also fail but that's what I'm curious about. Can you post the **exact** script you ran?

Comment: @EtanReisner Sorry for the delay but there was someone on the phone. After I hitted `ctrl-v` then `a` it gives me `a` BUT only once, after that I'll have to hit `ctrl-v` again in order to get one of those characters again. Hang on, I'll update the original post with the bash script.

Comment: @user2941923 Yes, as I said `ctrl-v` is `quoted-insert` (to use the correct readline terminology) which is documented to `Add the next character that you type to the line verbatim.` and it operates on exactly one character.

Comment: Yeah, other than being an entirely unnecessary use of a heredoc/EOF that script cannot possibly have caused this problem.

Comment: Well it did :'( Should I re-install the servers?